# Are multiple server blocks or one server block with redirects preferable in NGINX? Why?

Tags: nginx

I want to use an NGINX configuration to redirect non-www to www and http to https. I have seen two methods to do this. One uses multiple server blocks, two of which redirect to the third, like so:

```
server {
    listen      80;   #listen for all the HTTP requests
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return      301         https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate     ssl.crt; #you have to put here...
    ssl_certificate_key ssl.key; #   ...paths to your certificate files
    return      301     https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;

    ssl_certificate     ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl.key;

    # Omitting rest of configuration for brevity.
}
```

The second option is to have ONE server block listening to 80 and 443, and use an if statement within that block, like this:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    listen      [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;

    server_name   example.com www.example.com;

    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)) {
        return 301 https://$1$request_uri;
    }

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    ...
}
```

Is one of these methods the best practice in NGINX? If so, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use multiple server blocks, and within each server use locations rather than if statements. It's more efficient and the behavior is more predictable.

Nginx article "[if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)" is a necessary read. You should also read "[common pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/)"